# User defined function for creating Row only listing first column of matrix or first element of a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, arguments

I cannot figure out why my `rowNameValue[]` is only listing the first part of a column or vector. Below is the code.

```
objectName = Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], {HoldFirst}];
ClearAll[m, b]
m = {{1, 0, -5}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
MatrixQ[m]
b = {1, 4, 0};
VectorQ[b]
rowNameValue[symbol_, name_ : Null] := Block[{id, fn},
   id = If[Head[name] === String, name, objectName[symbol], 
     objectName[symbol]];
   id = If[MatrixQ[symbol] || VectorQ[symbol], Style[id, Bold], id, 
     id];
   fn = If[MatrixQ[symbol] || VectorQ[symbol], MatrixForm, 
     TraditionalForm, StandardForm];
   {Row[{id, " \[Rule] "}, " "], Apply[fn, symbol]}
   ];
dataIn[m_, b_] = Block[{}, Grid[{
    rowNameValue[m, "m"],
    rowNameValue[b, "b"]
    }]]
dataIn[m, b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Apply[fn, symbol]` with `fn @ symbol`:

```
dataIn[m, b]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it worked